# Proving that $S=\{ x \in (X,\| \cdot \|) : \|x\| =1 \}$ is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, spheres

**Exercise :**

> Show that the unit sphere $$S=\{x \in (X,\|\cdot \|) : \|x\| =1\}$$ of a normed space, is a closed set.

**Attempt :**

For a set to be closed, its complement must be an open set. Define the complement of $S$ to be :

$$S^c = \{ x \in (X, \|\cdot \|) : \|x\| <1 \}\cup\{x\in (X,\|\cdot\|):\|x\|>1\}$$

**Note :** We have **NOT** yet been introduced to handling maps for such proofs in our functional analysis course, so it may not be the best approach for my understanding.

**Question :** How would one proceed with proving the fact stated in the exercise?

Comment: This is not the complement of $S$.

Comment: @EduardoLonga I will edit accordingly. Still can't see how to approach it.

Comment: The norm function is continuous...

Comment: For example, to show $\{ x \mid \lVert x \rVert > 1 \}$ is open: show that if $\lVert x_0 \rVert > 1$ and $\lVert x - x_0 \rVert < \lVert x_0 \rVert - 1$, then $\lVert x \rVert > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I think it is much more elegant to use continuity, here is an approach which does not use continuity:

Let first $x_0 \in \{x\in X \mid \Vert x\Vert < 1 \} = S_1^c.$
Take $r = 1-\Vert x_0\Vert > 0.$ Then the open ball
$$B(x_0, r) = \{ y \in X \mid \Vert x_0-y \Vert < r \}$$ is fully contained in $S_1^c$, since for any $y\in B(x_0,r),$ we have
$$ \Vert y\Vert = \Vert x_0 - y\Vert + \Vert x_0 \Vert < r+\Vert x_0 \Vert = 1-\Vert x_0\Vert + \Vert x_0 \Vert = 1. $$
Hence $S_1^c$ is open.

Now let $x_0 \in \{x\in X \mid \Vert x\Vert > 1 \} = S_2^c,$ and take $r = \Vert  x_0 \Vert - 1 > 0.$ Then the open ball $B(x_0,r)$ is fully contained in $S_2^c$, since for any $y\in B(x_0, r)$, the reverse triangle inequality gives
$$ \Vert y \Vert \geq \Vert x_0 \Vert - \Vert y-x_0 \Vert > \Vert x_0 \Vert - r = \Vert x_0 \Vert - (\Vert x_0 \Vert - 1) = 1. $$
Hence $S_2^c$ is open.

Being a union of two open sets, $S^c = S_1^c \cup S_2^c$ is open, so that $S$ is closed.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your non-map input ! Nicely elaborated and easy to follow ! Wanted to ask, is the solution below by ZAF as well correct ? Seems so trivial.

Comment: It is indeed correct, as far as I can see. But it also uses the continuity of $x \mapsto \Vert x\Vert,$ which, as far as I understood, you did not want to use? If you are going to use continuity anyway, then it's easier to just say that the preimage under $f(x)=\Vert x\Vert$ of the closed set $\{1\}$ is closed, by continuity.

Comment: The continuity of the norm as a function is something I can use, what I cannot use (not that I do not want) is the maps stuff (inverse images etc), because we have not been introduced to them yet as part of our functional analysis course, thus I have completely no understanding of them.

Comment: The notion of inverse image is usually introduced already in the first calculus course, or even in the elementary mathematics course, so I would not expect that you will be introduced to it in the functional analysis course, which is an advanced course.

Comment: Well the next part on our course notes is elaborating over operators, so I guess this is where we will implement them in our studies regarding functional analysis.

Comment: Might be. In any case, good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks a lot and especially for the nicely elaborated answer !

Comment: I'm glad if it helped!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot *define* freely the complement of a set. In this case,$$S^\complement=\bigl\{x\in X\,|\,\|x\|>1\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{x\in X\,|\,\|x\|<1\bigr\}.$$Yes, we can prove that it is an open set, but it is simpler to see that $S$ is the inverse image of the closed set $\{1\}$ with respect to the continuous function $\|\cdot\|$. It follows that $S$ is closed.

Comment: We haven't been introduced to handling maps yet in functional analysis, so I should probably seek an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- show that the norm $N:(X,||\cdot||)\to\mathbb{R}$ mapping $x$ to $||x||$ is a continuous map,
- show that the inverse image of an open set by a continuous map is still open,
- rewrite $S^c$ as $N^{-1}(]-1,1[)\cup N^{-1}(]1,+\infty[)$,
- conclude.

Comment: We haven't been introduced to handling maps yet in functional analysis, so I should probably seek an alternative approach.

Comment: Can you deal with sequences, saying that a set is closed if every sequence of elements of this set which converges has the property that the limit is still inside the set?

Answer (score 1):

Take a convergent sequence on the sphere and shows that it converges there

Let $(x_{n})$ a convergent sequence in $S$, suppose $x_{n} \to y$

Let's see $y \in S$

$||x_{n}|| = 1$ $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$||.||$ is a continuos function, then $1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} ||x_{n}|| = ||\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}|| = ||y||$

Then $y \in S$

So $S$ is a closed set.